# Detect tap touches on CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calayer, quartz-core

My setup is as follows

```
- UIView
    - CALayer (container)
        -CAShapeLayer
        -CAShapeLayer
        -..
```

And i want to detect tap touches on every shapelayer to change its color

I have put a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my `UIView` and have the following code

```
CGPoint point = [self tapWithPoint:[recognizer locationInView:pieView]];

PieSliceLayer* layerThatWasTapped = (PieSliceLayer *)[_containerLayer hitTest:point];
[(PieSliceLayer *)[layerThatWasTapped modelLayer] setFillColor:UIColor.redColor];
```

But it seems that it only changes 1 CAShapeLayer always the first that was added.

Comment: Have you done any custom hit testing in the PieSliceLayer class?

Comment: [This](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/) is a good place to start reading about hit testing paths

Comment: If your hit test is not customized, your code detects whether the tap point lies inside the bounding rect(angular area) of your layer. This probably is not what you want.

Comment: i don't have custom hit testing